# GWT register key event from a text field

Tags: gwt

Hey,
I'm running GWT on ubuntu and trying to learn by following the tutorial guide found on [Google](http://code.google.com/intl/sv/webtoolkit/overview.html) . I have some problem with making a textfield register when user hit the enter button. It works with specificing arbitrary character, so I don't think it is any problem with the code. So it probably is that `KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER` isn't supported in linux? What else can I write instead to make it read when user hit enter?

```
    newSymbolTextBox.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
      public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
        if (event.getCharCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
          addStock();
          System.out.println("Foo");
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115770/keypressevent-getcharcode-returning-0-for-all-special-keys-like-enter-tab-es

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `getKeyCode()` method that you'll find on the native event.

```
if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER)
  System.out.println("Foo");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you think that KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER isn't supported in linux you can just replace it by:

```
event.getCharCode() == 13
```